# How to round sharp edges of iregular mesh

Tags: mesh, workflow

I have an irregular mesh created with Boolean modifier of a 3D scan and two icospheres. The mesh has two sharp edges which I would like to round out:

[image]

I can smooth out the top edge using Smooth Vertex to something I could accept but the bottom edge does not get smoothed out enough to be called rounding.

My clumsy attempt to show what my aim could be is this - the red arrow points to what is only a part of what I'd like to get (it should be similar but all around the sharp edge):

[image]

I have tried using Bevel, Multiresolution, Subdivision Surface modifiers but cannot get enough of beveling (when I get any).
I also used Bevel in Edit mode but it creates ugly artifacts because the mesh is irregular.

I cannot do this by sculpting because this is only a part of a workflow aimed to process many of similar shapes.

I've read about 15 other question with similar subject but none of them offered a solution I could use.

The question is this: **Is there a way to bevel the sharp edges that is not manual?**

Info: I have cleaned up the mesh with Triangulate, Remove Doubles and have removed zero faces with Edge Collapse. The mesh passes the "Check all" test in 3D Printing addon with all tests 0 (except the Overhang Face, of course).

The file with the above sample is here: [image]

Comment: Did you try subdivide smooth?

Comment: In order to smoothen those sharp edges most likely you'll need to change topology, at least in that area. Neither Bevel nor Subsurf won't work well with tiny and very distorted faces.

Comment: Blender is not a good tool to do what you want - it does not have the things you need. Download trial of Zbrush and run *Polish* pass over your shape or use the ZBrushes smooth brush that will smooth this topology correctly. In Blender you need to retopologize to do anything with this.

Comment: @Georges, yes, Subdivide Smooth only "rounds" the edge a bit. I'd like to round it more than that.

Comment: @Mr Zak & Jerryno, is there a simple way to change the topology of this thing?

Comment: @spacer Try to use remesh modifier or enable looptools addon and use Relax operation.

Comment: I know you said`not manually but proportional editing or sculpting is an option

Comment: @Denis, thanks, but neither worked. The Remesh messes up the (irregular but nice) mesh and the LoopTools Relax just spreads the vertices along the edge (I thought it might help the Bevel but it doesn't).

Comment: I don't think there's automated and fast solution as of now. I know of [this WIP addon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JyxGBd7QDwc) however it wasn't finished yet and there isn't much information about it. I also saw [InstantMeshes](https://blendersensei.com/forums/topic/instant-meshes-automatic-retopology-for-blender/) which probably have [import-export integration](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?387378-WIP-InstantMesher-automated-export-and-import-for-Instant-Meshes-%28Windows-Linux%29) but I'm not aware of how good it works. Solutions in Blender mean retopo by hand.

Comment: Thanks @Mr Zak, the WIP addon looks interesting but I couldn't find anything except videos ...

Answer (score 2):

You need first to simplify the mesh using Decimate modifier, here are the steps:

1- Use Decimate Modifier, set Ratio to a low value I used 0.042 for this example.
[image]

2- Apply the Decimate modifier, then go to Edit Mode, select the edges you want to Bevel.
[image]

3- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> to bevel the edges, don't use Clamp, but keep an eye on those adjacent edges, a little overlapping will be correct next step.
[image]
4- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> and select Remove Doubles, fiddle with the amount until you weld very close together vertices, in this example, I used 0.5.
[image]
5- Now add a Subdivision Surface Modifier, if you haven't set the shading to smooth yet, it's time to do. This is the final result, of course you can choose the parameters you need for the previous steps, I put the values according to what I think you're looking for.
[image]
Hope this helped, Happy Blending!

Comment: Thanks! Although it is not really what I can use (I need to keep the shape as close as possible to the original, except the edges, so I cannot decimate the mesh so much) it gave me an idea. I'll get back after I try it.

Comment: In this case, the only thing I can think of, is using a project knife, or a boolean, to cut the edge, but that will take some manual work.