# How to round the edges of a mesh with small faces?

Tags: modeling, bevel

I'm trying to round the edges on the top of this model.
[image: irritating soccer ball mesh]

Inner (90˚) edge is easy – I can just apply a bevel modifier and limit by angle. I'm having trouble with the outer edge. The bevel modifier either does nothing or makes a mess because the faces near that edge are too small. I've messed around for a few hours and have tried using the sculpting tools, but they don't work well because of only having two faces on the top. I tried selecting all the vertices near the edge and scaling them in towards the center, but it doesn't look good and will take a really long time to get a good result. I also tried doing some boolean stuff with a torus to cut off the sharp edge, but I couldn't get it to look right.

I found [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52273/how-to-round-sharp-edges-of-iregular-mesh) that addresses almost the exact same problem, but the solution given would ruin the soccer ball look of the model and seems to only be a visual solution. I plan on 3D printing this (soccer ball napkin rings), so the model itself actually needs rounded edges. How can I do this?

I created this model by loosely following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AYC69tt-KMI) then using two boolean modifiers with a cylinder and a rectangular prism. Do I need to somehow model this in a different way to be able to round the edges?

[.blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rVisTodwtRbwPsoCWT-SkXlhELB_oYC0/view)

[edit]

Selecting the very top outside edges and using proportional editing (sharp mode) to scale them inwards starts to do what I want but the resulting curve is lopsided and not a proper bevel.
[image: ugly bevel]

This is what I'm looking for (except with the soccer ball pattern)
[image: fillet from fusion 360 1]
[image: fillet from fusion 360 2]

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at this but honestly stuggled to find a good solution.

[image]

This was the best I could come up with given the starting point. If this is what you are looking for then I can reproduce the steps. Let me know. Maybe others have different ideas.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt! I ended up redoing the model in Fusion 360, which made the edge beveling much easier due to the way it handles 3D objects. If you feel like it, maybe explaining generally what you did or your approach to the problem might help other Blender noobs like me who may stumble across this post in the future. :)